# Prevent hashtags affecting back button for Cycle2

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm using a Cycle2 slideshow with hashtags to allow sharing for specific images, but I don't want visitors to have to press the back button repeatedly to go to the previous page. Is there any way to make the back button ignore hashtags?

In case it helps, here is the hashtag plugin for Cycle2 (credit to Cycle2 of course):

```
function (e) {
    "use strict";
    function t(t, i) {
        var n;
        return t._hashFence ? (t._hashFence = !1, void 0) : (n = window.location.hash.substring(1), t.slides.each(function (s) {
            if (e(this).data("cycle-hash") == n) {
                if (i === !0)t.startingSlide = s; else {
                    var o = s > t.currSlide;
                    t.nextSlide = s, t.API.prepareTx(!0, o)
                }
                return!1
            }
        }), void 0)
    }

    e(document).on("cycle-pre-initialize", function (i, n) {
        t(n, !0), n._onHashChange = function () {
            t(n, !1)
        }, e(window).on("hashchange", n._onHashChange)
    }), e(document).on("cycle-update-view", function (e, t, i) {
        i.hash && "#" + i.hash != window.location.hash && (t._hashFence = !0, window.location.hash = i.hash)
    }), e(document).on("cycle-destroyed", function (t, i) {
        i._onHashChange && e(window).off("hashchange", i._onHashChange)
    })
}
(jQuery),
/*! loader plugin for Cycle2;  version: 20131121 */
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you:)

Comment: formatted code is your best friend!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
window.location.hash = i.hash;
```

use

```
window.location.replace(i.hash);
```

This will replace the current history entry rather then creating/adding a new one. That way the previous history entry will remain the same throughout your slideshow.